# Script for passing traffic

Tags: shell-script, scripting, http

I'm trying to write a script to test our proxy servers to see if they're passing traffic. 
I wrote this code below to implement "httpie" tool but still having issues. Can someone please take a look and let me know what's wrong with this code? 
The code is supposed to check all the proxy IP addresses to make sure all IPs are passing traffic and if each proxy returns 200 then the code should exit but if we have an issue, the code should then send me an email saying the specific IP address returned this specific error.

```
#!/bin/bash
proxy_targets="http://10.1.1.4:3128 http://10.1.1.5:3128 http://10.1.1.6:3128"

failed_hosts=""

for i in $proxy_targets
do

if http --check-status --ignore-stdin --timeout=2.5 --proxy=http:$i HEAD www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt &> /dev/null; then
    echo 'OK!'
else
    case $? in
        2) echo 'Request timed out!'| mail -s "The following WSA has failed to pass traffic with the following error" moe.abdel@childrens.ha
rvard.edu  ;;
        3) echo 'Unexpected HTTP 3xx Redirection!'| mail -s "The following WSA has failed to pass traffic with the following error" katkota@newwork.com  ;;
        4) echo 'HTTP 4xx Client Error!'| mail -s "The following WSA has failed to pass traffic with the following error" katkota@newwork.com  ;;
        5) echo 'HTTP 5xx Server Error!'| mail -s "The following WSA has failed to pass traffic with the following error" katkota@newwork.com  ;;
        6) echo 'Exceeded --max-redirects=<n> redirects!'| mail -s "The following WSA has failed to pass traffic with the following error" katkota@newwork.com  ;;
        *) echo 'Other Error!'| mail -s "The following WSA has failed to pass traffic with the following error" katkota@newwork.com ;;
    esac
fi
done;
```

Comment: What is going wrong with it?  Also you should store your targets in an array `proxy_targets=( ... )` rather than a variable.  You would call like: `for i in "${proxy_targets[@]}"`.  Also do you notice you have http both in the variable and the http argument?  So you are calling: `--proxy=http:http://10.1.1.4:3128`

Comment: It runs fine but if one of the proxy is not passing traffic, i got email telling me the error but it won't tell me which IP returned the error. How can i get the IP that had the issue to show up in the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the IP stored in `i` so you can add it to your email like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

proxy_targets=( 'http://10.1.1.4:3128' 'http://10.1.1.5:3128' 'http://10.1.1.6:3128' )
failed_hosts=

for i in "${proxy_targets[@]}"
do
    exit_code=$(http --check-status --ignore-stdin --timeout=2.5 "--proxy=$i" HEAD www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt &> /dev/null; echo $?)
    if ((exit_code==0))
    then
        echo 'OK!'
    else
        ip=${i#http://}     # Removes http:// from variable
        ip=${ip%:[0-9]*}    # Removes port from the end
        case $exit_code in
            2)  echo 'Request timed out!' | \
                mail -s "The following WSA has failed to pass traffic: ${ip}, with the following error: $exit_code" moe.abdel@childrens.harvard.edu  
            ;;
            3)  echo 'Unexpected HTTP 3xx Redirection!' | \
                mail -s "The following WSA has failed to pass traffic: ${ip}, with the following error: $exit_code" katkota@newwork.com  
            ;;
            4)  echo 'HTTP 4xx Client Error!' | \
                mail -s "The following WSA has failed to pass traffic: ${ip}, with the following error: $exit_code" katkota@newwork.com  
            ;;
            5)  echo 'HTTP 5xx Server Error!' | \
                mail -s "The following WSA has failed to pass traffic: ${ip}, with the following error: $exit_code" katkota@newwork.com  
            ;;
            6)  echo 'Exceeded --max-redirects=<n> redirects!' | \
                mail -s "The following WSA has failed to pass traffic: ${ip}, with the following error: $exit_code" katkota@newwork.com  
            ;;
            *)  echo 'Other Error!' | \
                mail -s "The following WSA has failed to pass traffic: ${ip}, with the following error: $exit_code" katkota@newwork.com 
            ;;
        esac
    fi
done
```

- I put `proxy_targets` into an array
- I quoted `--proxy=$i` and removed the extra `http://` from it
- I'm storing the exit code in a variable so it's preserved after the variable assignment
- Using parameter expansion I have `ip` to the current address removing the http:// and port
- I've added `ip` and `exit_code` to the mail subject.